# How to check in after phase of Validations phase if validation has failed?

Tags: java, validation, jsf

I have written a `PhaseListener` in which I am checking for the Validations phase. Is there a way using which I can check in the `afterPhase()` method of listener that validation has failed and the next phase after the Validation phase will be Render Response phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using FacesContext, can you check if there are any enqueued messages? Eg.

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Iterator<FacesMessage> messages = context.getMessages();
```

hope that helps.

Comment: Thats exactly what I am doing now, FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getMaximumSeverity != null, thanks :)

Comment: If you have your own validators that can enque INFO or WARNING messages then you may have to ignore it.

Answer (score 6):

If you're on JSF 2.0, just use [`FacesContext#isValidationFailed()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isValidationFailed%28%29) to check it.

```
if (context.isValidationFailed()) {
    // Validation has failed.
}
```

You can by the way also check for it in the view side as follows:

```html
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{facesContext.validationFailed}">
    <p>Validation has failed.</p>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the maximum severity for error in the FacesContext

```
Severity maximumSeverity = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getMaximumSeverity();
boolean validationFailed=false;
if (maximumSeverity != null
        && (maximumSeverity==FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR || maximumSeverity
            ==FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL)) {
    validationFailed=true;
}
```

If the value of the validationFailed is true then there are some error messages present.