# In which jsf phase does @AssertTrue annotation checked?

Tags: tomcat, jsf-2, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I have a JSF application and I am using *@AssertTrue* on a method called *isPasswordsEquals()* to confirm a password match. However, the method doesn't seem to work correctly. It adds the error message to the context, but doesn't throw any exception when the passwords don't match. The ongoing transaction just completes.

Do I need call this function or it is called implicitly? I added -ea for tomcat startup parameters. Do  I need add anything in web.xml for assertion?

I am using tomcat 7, myfaces 2.1.10, jvm 7 and eclipse ide. and I have validation api 1.0 and hibernate validator 4.3.1 in my build path.

Comment: is rich:graphvalidate or f:validatebean required in view side

Comment: Related: [Perform action when jsf validation errors occur](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859951/1288)

Answer (score 0):

First off, Java assertions have nothing to do with Bean Validation and constraints like *@AssertTrue*. They are completely different things. For that reason using the -ea JVM option will not do anything.

My guess is that *isPasswordEquals* is not evaluated, because JSF is actually not validating whole beans, bu only a given property via *Validator#validateValue*. Your method is not connected to a concrete property and hence does not get validated. Does validation work for the password fields themselves? For example, can you add something like *@NotNull* or *@NotEmpty* to them and the validation throws an exception. That would show that validation occurs for properties.

As far as I know, there is no way to use class level constraints or constraints on non property values with JSF. You would have to either make the validation call yourself in case you are using JPA, use the life cycle based validation on entity manager callbacks.

Comment: thanks for reply actually notnull and Email like validations doesnt work except i use rich:graphvalidator or f:validatebean(this is never worked the problem is about jsf imp version i guess)and what "your method is not connected a concrete property means " my method is  @AssertTrue(message = "Different passwords entered!")
 public boolean isPasswordsEquals() {
  return pass.equals(passcheck);
   
 } //pass and passcheck are entity members